# How do I track progress for individual achievements on Steam?

Tags: steam, achievements

I've seen it on a TF2 video that I can't find anymore, but I found another occasion of someone doing this here:

At the bottom right, it shows "Achievement progress" and it appears multiple times throughout the video as he activates more radios.

Comment: I don't have a source for this, but to the best of my knowledge this is entirely game-dependent. Valve's games likely try to show off what the steam achievements tracker is capable of. And, in my experience, most other developers just don't bother - they track the achievement progress internally and send the unlock code at once.

Answer (score 4):

You don't track the progress, it's up to each developer to implement progress for each achievement. Here is for example Euro Truck Simulator 2 with partial progress for 3 of it's achievements:

[image]

And here is Beat Saber not implementing progress for the Drum Kit and No Mistakes achievements:

[image]